# Django permission_required decorator doesn't redirect back after login

Tags: python, django, authentication

My request handlers have a `permission_required` decorator to force the user to login. Like so:

```
@permission_required("main.view_things", login_url="admin/login")
def homepage(request):
    # ...
```

This works fine. But if a login is required, the login page doesn't redirect back to the original page (here: `homepage`), but to some page in admin. Is there an easy fix, since this seems to be a pretty standard situation?

Comment: Try using separate `@login_required` And then `@permission_required` without login_url. It seems, the way you are doing redirect misses `next` parameter to login url, which should contain url to the current page, while default LoginView and @login_required decorator should handle it.

Comment: A better @permission_required decorator for Django
https://gist.github.com/scupython/4134071

Comment: @Som-1 Thanks, but that way the `next` parameter is still `/admin/login%3Fnext%3D/' instead of the current page